# How do I specify a dependency rule in Maven between files of certain suffixes?

Tags: java, dependencies, maven, generated-code

I have a Java program that generates Java classes for my application.
Basically it takes in a simple spec for a class and generates a specialized
form of Java bean. I want to integrate this into my Maven pom.xml so
that if the input file is changed, Maven automatically generates the
new .java file before the compile phase of Maven.

I know how to do this trivially in make but I didn't find anything
in the Maven doc with this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide much details on your code generation process but you could maybe simply invoke the code generator with the [**exec-maven-plugin**](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) (see the **Examples** section). The convention is to generate sources in `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/<tool>`. Then add the generated sources with the [**build-helper-plugin**](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin) and its [`add-sources`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) mojo. Bind every thing on the [`generate-sources`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) phase.

I'll just show the build-helper stuff below:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-mytool-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/mytool</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

You could also write a simple plugin to wrap your generator. In that case, have a look at the [Guide to generating sources](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-generating-sources.html).

PS: I may have missed something, there is a kind of mismatch between my answer and the title of your question.

Comment: My program takes a .bean file and generates a .java file:    


java BeanGenerator Foo.bean


will generate a Foo.java so I'm trying to find a mechanism inMaven/ant that allows me to specify this relationship so
it knows that when the .bean is newer than the .java it needs
to run this comm and line. My frustration is that this was
trivial in ye olde worlde make but it's not at all obvious
how to do this Maven/ant.

Comment: @Guy Ok. Then the suggested method will work (except it would run systematically).

Answer (score 0):

Maven have phase "[generate-sources](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-generating-sources.html)" for this